# Is it possible to open Labelimg in Angular with python backend?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, bounding-box

I want to use the image labeling python tool "LabelImg" in a browser with angular as front-end. Is it possible to do that?. If no , then how can labeling an image is done using angular so that the pixel values selected for each box in that image is set to back-end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. You need to create an api that you can send the image to the python backend and return the result after the python has finished processing the image.

Depending on the python algorithm runtime, you might need to make this task async which would ned more engineering: an api each for sending an image, checking for the labeling status, getting labeling result as well as a storage solution to store the image labeling status and result.

In layman terms, angular frontend and python backend are not coupled together. Angular gives you an interface to communicate to the end-user while the backend api's create a channel to communicate with the python service

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I need a clarification, is it possible to open the image using front-end itself?

Comment: Angular runs on javascript, python runs on .. python. Thus it is not possible to directly execute python from javascript. You need to execute it remotely, one way of which is the abovementioned api call.

Comment: You can also opt for a websocket connection which would give you a more direct communication channel, but the separation between angular and python cannot be avoided.

Comment: That said, you can of course design the angular webpage in such a way that would simulate "opening image in angular". That would first need you to display the initial image and then override it with the labeled image or draw additional objects over the image in angular. This, however, is an extension on above answer and only gives you an UX upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for responding. On more thing to know, we need to create the api call in angular?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a channel to pass the data between angular and python